# Hotkey to toggle another hotkey into a different function or mode

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to get a the hotkey LCTRL to toggle XButton2 into different modes.
The issue is that it's saying that there are duplicate hotkeys in the same script. I clearly don't know what's going on. Help?

```
~LCtrl::
actioncameratoggle := !actioncameratoggle
if actioncameratoggle
{
    ~XButton2::
    rTurn := !rTurn
    if rTurn
    {
    send {lctrl}
    mousemove, 800, 450
    send {ctrl}
    mousemove, 1600, 450
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
else
    {
    ~XButton2::
    {

    }
}
return
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With your Script You can not toggle with the same hotkeys, the reason is you  want to use the **if** with the **Else** commands > `if hotkey1:: else hotkey1::`, you will need the **#if** commands. Look to this example code.

You can Write this example.ahk Code and try it out on your Windows System.

Change the code a little bit for your needs, and it is done.

I did make the script so that the other guys can simple test it out.

```
; [+ = Shift] [! = Alt] [^ = Ctrl] [# = Win] 

a := 1 

#If mode1 ; All hotkeys below this line will only work if mode1 is TRUE or 1
    t::1
    ; Here you can put your first hotkey code ~XButton2::
#If

#If mode2 ; All hotkeys below this line will only work if mode2 is TRUE or 1
    t::2
    ; And here you can put your second hotkey code ~XButton2::
#If

; toggle between [t::1] and [t::2]
;a = 1   => t::1
;a = 2   => t::2

;type LCtrl key to toggle between two the same hotkeys
;you can test it out in notepad - if you then type the key t
~LCtrl::  
if (a=1)
{
mode1 = 1
mode2 = 0
a := 2
}else{
mode1 = 0
mode2 = 1
a := 1
}
```